# autocomplete return '0 results'

Tags: php, autocomplete

recently started coding, tried to use prepared statements for the first time, but it's returning '0 results' and I can't find the error.

Autocomplete was working without prepared statements, but don't know where I'm going wrong now.

```
<?php
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName= "vlucht";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

$id = $_GET['q'];
$disc = "%" . strtolower($id) . "%";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT postgemeente FROM overzicht WHERE LOWER (postgemeente) LIKE ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $disc);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["postgemeente"]. "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Did you check that that query returns any rows if you run it in phpMyAdmin

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using prepare->bind->execute ..... you need to remove this line

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

See comments

```
<?php
// help with debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName= "vlucht";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

$id = $_GET['q'];
$disc = "%" . strtolower($id) . "%";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT postgemeente FROM overzicht WHERE LOWER (postgemeente) LIKE ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $disc);
$stmt->execute();

// remove you are doing it differently now
//$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// add to get a result object from a statement object
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["postgemeente"]. "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```